# Append string in a specific place of a text file

Tags: c#, .net

I have hundreds of files in a directory. Many of the text files have the Code Column values as  blank and i need to iterate over all the text files and fill it. I am able to write the code to add the code value in a  new line, but i am not able to write it under code column. String value is: "STRINGTOENTER". I only want it be entered in the 1st line after the header. The last line should be left alone

```
 
Id    Code    File_Number   Suffix  Check_Number    Check_Date

047           7699      01          99999       11/11/2012
1   -6.15
```

Below is my code snippets that add the value at a newline. I think I need to do a regular expression or a tab delimited type solution here.

```
 public static void AddAStringtoAllTextFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\ur\Desktop\TestFiles\";
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            for (int i = 0; i < fileEntries.Length; i++)
            {

                File.AppendAllText(fileEntries[i], "STRINGTOENTER" + Environment.NewLine);
           }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `AppendAllText` writes to the end of the file. That's it. If you want anything more complicated, you'll need to read the file, make the change, and write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each file has the right tab delimitation (and that's a big assumption given the question quality)

```
// Get the files
var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);

// iterate through each file name
foreach (var entry in fileEntries)
{

  // Load the File into the lines array
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(entry);

  // Iterate over each line
  if(lines.Length >1)
  {
     // Split the lines by tab
     var split = lines[1].Split('\t');
     // your code should be at array index 1
     split[1] = "STRINGTOENTER";
     // write the whole line back
     lines[1] = string.Join("\t", split);

     // write the file
     File.WriteAllLines(entry, lines);
  }

}
```

<sub>***Note*** : you should probably do this with a CSV parser, this was only for academic purposes and totally untested</sub>

Comment: @Heike you should add this to your question "I only want it be entered in the 1st line after the header."

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**
please try this with the assumption that its space(s) delimited.

its working on my VS2017 and kindly add the using statement on the top as below .

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions

    public static void AddAStringtoAllTextFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\ur\Desktop\TestFiles\";
            var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            int indexPosition2InsertData=1;
            foreach (var entry in fileEntries)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(entry);
                for (var index = 1; index < lines.Length; index++) //starting  from first row, leaving the header
                {
                    var split= Regex.Split(lines[index].Trim(), @"\s{1,}"); //reading the line with space(s)
                    if(split.Length==5) //edited //checking if the row is not blank
                    {
                        var list = split.ToList(); //convert to list to insert
                        list.Insert(indexPosition2InsertData, "STRINGTOENTER"); //inserting at the index 1
                        lines[index] = string.Join("\t", list);
                    }
                }
                File.WriteAllLines(entry, lines);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I am getting this after running the code.

```
Id    Code    File_Number   Suffix  Check_Number    Check_Date

047 STRINGTOENTER   7699    01  99999   11/11/2012
1   -6.15
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The value got inserted in the 3rd line as well. I only want it be entered in the 1st line after the header.

Comment: @Heike,As I can understand I updated the code and also please share an exact text file string in order to reproduce.

Comment: I can't upload the exact file because it's from my company. Both of your solutions worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Cheers, keep coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

I want to show my desired solution based on your input. Amazing how a simple piece of code can contribute to solving a larger and a complex problem. Thanks again!

```
     public static void AddClientCodetoAllTextFiles(string update_batch_with_clientcode, string batchfilepathtobeupdated)
    {      

        try
        {
            var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@batchfilepathtobeupdated.Trim());

            foreach (var entry in fileEntries)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(entry);

                if (lines.Length > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        var split = lines[i].Split('\t');
                        split[1] = update_batch_with_clientcode.Trim();
                        lines[i] = string.Join("\t", split);

                        File.WriteAllLines(entry, lines);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```